# Daemonizing a child process consequently changes its PID

Tags: ruby, process, multiprocessing, fork, daemon

```
pid = Process.fork
#sleep 4
Process.daemon nil, true
if pid.nil? then
    job.exec
else
    #Process.detach(pid)
end
```

The `pid` returned by `Process.fork` is changed as soon as `Process.daemon(nil, true)` is run. Is there a way to preserve/track the pid of a forked child process that is subsequently daemonized?

I want to know the pid of the child process from within the parent process. So far the only way I've been able to communicate the pid is through `IO.pipe` writing the `Process.pid` to IO#write and then using IO#read from the parent to read it. Less than ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions I've come up with involve using Ruby's IO to pass the pid from the child process to the parent.

```
r, w = IO.pipe
pid = Process.fork
Process.daemon nil, true
w.puts Process.pid
if pid.nil? then
  job.exec
else
  #Process.detach(pid)
end

pid = r.gets
```

Another solution involves invoking the [process status](http://t-a-w.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-kill-all-your-children.html) of all processes that have controlling terminals.

```
def Process.descendant_processes(base=Process.pid)
descendants = Hash.new{|ht,k| ht[k]=[k]}
Hash[*`ps -eo pid,ppid`.scan(/\d+/).map{|x|x.to_i}].each{|pid,ppid|
descendants[ppid] << descendants[pid]
}
descendants[base].flatten - [base]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Process.daemon` does it's own fork, that's why the pid is changed. If you need to know the daemon's pid, why not use Process.pid in the forked part of `if`?

```
pid = Process.fork
#sleep 4
Process.daemon nil, true
if pid.nil? then
    job.exec
else
    Process.detach(Process.pid)
end
```

Comment: I should have been more clear about where I want to retrieve the `pid`. I want to know the pid in the parent process.